# Initialize interpreter with variables

Tags: python, ipython, interpreter, python-interactive

How do I initialize the python interpreter such that it already has variables in its memory?  For example, how could I initialize a[n i]Python interpreter, and type as my first input:

```
In [1]: today
Out[1]: '2015-05-05 17:49:32.726496'
```

without first binding the name `str(today = datetime.datetime.today())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ipython, you can configure it to load scripts automatically for you.

Run

```
$ ipython profile create
```

which will create default profile in your home directory.

Create a file called `~/.ipython/ipython_init.py` and add

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today
```

Now at the end of `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`, add this line so that it will load that file every time interpreter starts

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = ['~/.ipython/ipython_init.py']
```

Next time when you launch ipython shell, you can access those variables.

```
In [1]: today
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 2, 13, 31, 26, 776744)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three options for the standard Python interpreter:

- [`python -i setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i), as explained in [tzaman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065745/908494)
- dropping into interactive mode from within `setup.py`, as explained in [Jordan P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065768/908494)
- setting the environment variable [`PYTHONSTARTUP=setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP).

That last one is useful if you want to start and stop Python hundreds of times. Just `export PYTHONSTARTUP=setup.py` and as long as you're in the same shell, it'll always load `setup.py`. Or, if you want it more permanent, put it in your profile (or Windows System Control Panel Environment Variables or whatever).

`PYTHONSTARTUP` is especially handy with `virtualenvwrapper` and its [`post_activate`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins.html#plugins-post-activate) hook. Just set the hook to `export PYTHONSTARTUP=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/setup.py` and you can have a different setup for each environment.

In fact, what `-i` actually does is, in effect, override `PYTHONSTARTUP` with a one-time temporary value.

---

IPython has its own very powerful (but somewhat complicated) [configuration and customization system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/index.html). You can build a dozen different profiles, and edit each one to enable and disable the use of `-i` and `PYTHONSTARTUP`, change `PYTHONSTARTUP` to use a different variable name, execute various lines of code each time a kernel is started, and so on. Most of what you want is under [Terminal IPython options](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/options/terminal.html), if you're using it at the terminal.

Comment: Neat, did not know about the env var option.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer, you can explicitly drop into interactive mode like this:

```
// setup.py
import code, datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
code.interact(local=locals())
```

execute normally

```
python setup.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script containing your "setup" code, and then execute it and enter interactive mode.

For example:

```
# foo.py
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today
```

Run with:

```
python -i foo.py
>>> today
'2015-05-05 17:49:32.726496'
```

I believe IPython should support the same option. The other alternative for IPython specifically is to just start it, then say:

```
In [1]: %run foo.py
```

Which will run that script in your current shell, giving you access to everything defined there.