# print greeting message when entering python interpreter

Tags: python, ipython, interpreter, python-interactive

How do I print a greeting message when I initialize a python interpreter?  For example, if I were to [initialize a python interpreter with custom pre-defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065694/initialize-interpreter-with-variables), how might I advertise those variables to the user?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: use the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable to specify a file. python -h gives the details

Answer (score 6):

There is an environment variable called `PYTHONSTARTUP` that describes a path to a Python file to be executed on the invocation of Python shell. The script can contain normal Python code that is executed on invocation, therefore variables, prints or whatever else you want. It can be set in your ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP="$HOME/.pythonrc"
```

and then creating the file itself

```
cat > ~/.pythonrc << EOF
print 'Hello World!'
EOF
```

The output when starting python then looks somewhat like this

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:02:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Hello World!
>>>
```

Because it is a normal Python file, setting the variables and showing them/announcing availability can be done like this:

```
foo = 'Hello'
bar = 12.4123

print 'The following variables are available for use\nfoo: {}\nbar: {}'.format(foo, bar)
```

Output when invoking a Python repl and printing variable `foo`:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:02:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
The following variables are available for use
foo: Hello
bar: 12.4123
>>> print foo
Hello
```

iPython acts different in a sense that it does not execute your PYTHONSTARTUP file, but has it's own mechanism called profiles. Default profile can be modified in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`, where each `*.py` and `*.ipy` file is executed (see `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/README`).

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a console from a script using the built-in console or IPython's console.

If you want to use Python's built-in [console](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.interact), pass the `banner` argument.  Assuming you have a dictionary of variables to inject:

```
from code import interact
vars = {'hello': 'world'}
message = 'Extra vars: {}'.format(', '.join(vars))
interact(banner=message, local={'hello': 'world'})
```

With IPython's [console](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.embed.html?highlight=embed#IPython.terminal.embed.embed), pass `banner1`.

```
from IPython import embed
embed(banner1=message, user_ns={'hello': 'world'})
```